# Android - Getting Started with PhoneGap application

Tags: android, cordova

I have started to working with phoneGap application for android. I followed the steps from

http://i-programmer.info/programming/mobile/3037-getting-started-with-phonegap.html?start=1

But I'm getting the error as follows

[image]

**Issue Details:** While creating the New Android project I forgot to check the "create the new activity" checkbox, Now I have checked that box, Successfully created the new PhoneGap application.

**Solution:**

I have followed the steps as below

> 1. Download the Android PhoneGap application from
>
>    https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android
> 2. Copy Android folder and paste in the Documents folder
> 3. Start the Eclipse and create the new android application
> 4. While giving the Project name check "**Choose from existing source**" and browse the location as the "/document/Android/Samples"
> 5. then press **Next** and Choose the **AVD**,
> 6. Check the **CreateActivity** and press "**Finish**" button.

Now you can run this project.

Comment: You are asking about PhoneGap-SDK ah?

Comment: On the back of @Neil's comment, have you installed the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the way you created the android project. In the screenshot the project is marked as Android project, as far I can recognize, but doesn't contain Android libraries which are usually added automatically when you create the project. That's why it can't find the Android classes.

Maybe try with this guide, it's quite easy to follow:

http://phonegap.com/start#android

You could try also to run an (only)Android Hello World, to see if you can create an Android project correctly (Create the project as described in the guide and running, before adding PhoneGap stuff, would do this).

Answer (score 0):

these are the steps for installing Phonegap for any windows system.

1. Install Java (Set the path in environmental variables)
2. Download ADT Bundle and extract it and set the path in environmental variables.
3. Download and install Node.js from http://nodejs.org/ link. (Set the path in environmental variables if not set automatically)
4. Download Apache ANT. Extract it and set the path in environmental variables.

Once you are done with the above open your cmd prompt in windows and type 'npm'.

If it doesn't show error it means that you are good upto here.

Now type the following cmd.

C:/>npm install -g phonegap

Phonegap will be installed in your computer.

Now type the following command.

C:/>phonegap

If it doesn't show any error you are good to go by following the remaining steps from the http://phonegap.com/install/ website.

But if it shows any error, It means you need to set the path in the environmental variables.

Once you set it you can go with the remaining steps.